# XMLHttpRequests, POST data custom headers and verification

Tags: header, xmlhttprequest, base64, md5

I am asking for feedback. I have been trying to find a good method of verification of client sent POST data and came across the Content-MD5 header.

Here is my solution, the first part is using the jQuery .ajax() function in the form of a simple to use plug-in. It does require the [pidder encryption libraries](https://www.pidder.com/pidcrypt/) for the md5() and base64_encode() function necessary for the Content-MD5 header.

```
<script src="javascripts/pidcrypt.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/pidcrypt_util.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/md5.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
 $.fn.AJAX = function(method) {
  var defaults = {
   formID: $(this),
   appID: 'jQuery.AJAX',
   cache: true,
   context: $(this),
   type: 'json',
   callback: function(){},
   errCallback: function(){}
  };
  var methods = {
   init: function(o){
    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, o);
    $('#'+opts.formID.attr('id')).on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
      form: opts.formID.attr('id'),
      url: opts.formID.attr('action'),
      type: opts.formID.attr('method'),
      data: opts.formID.serialize(),
      context: opts.context,
      cache: opts.cache,
      crossDomain: (opts.type==='jsonp') ? true : false,
      dataType: opts.type,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Alt-Referer', opts.appID);
       if (opt.formID.serialize()){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Alt-Referer', pidCryptUtil.encodeBase64(pidCrypt.MD5($(this).serialize())));
       } else {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Alt-Referer', pidCryptUtil.encodeBase64(pidCrypt.MD5(appID)));
       }
      },
      success: function(x){
       ((opts.callback)&&($.isFunction(opts.callback))) ?
         opts.callback.call(x) : console.log(x);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
       ((opts.errCallback)&&($.isFunction(opts.errCallback))) ?
         opts.errCallback.call(xhr, status, error) : console.log(xhr+status+error);
      }
     });
     return true;
    });
   }
  };
  if (methods[method]){
   return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  } else if ((typeof method==='object')||(!method)){
   return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
  } else {
   console.log('Method '+method+' does not exist');
  }
 };
})(jQuery);}
```

To use the plug-in simple create an HTML form like so...

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="proxy.php">
 <label for="name">Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="John Doe" required="required" />
 <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required="required" />
 <label for="email">Confirm Email: <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required="required" />
</form>
```

Now bind the plug-in to the form like so...

```
$('#test').AJAX();
```

At this point a working client method of sending POST data to the proxy.php script is in place. The one major difference here is that instead of just sending the forms post data some custom headers are being sent along with the XMLHttpRequest'ed form data.

Now on the server a couple of simple verifications are performed. First check to ensure the request was a XMLHttpRequest, then check to ensure the X-Alt-Referer matches, next it will check to ensure the post data matches the same post data (serialized) hash matches prior to processing. Technically it works much like a checksum.

```
<?php
/* set the custom applicaiton string */
$appID = 'jQuery.AJAX'; // the plug-in URL https://github.com/jas-/jQuery.AJAX

/* verify an XMLHttpRequest was made */
if (strcmp($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'], 'XMLHttpRequest')!==0){
 exit('An XMLHttpRequest was not made');
}

/* verify associated X-ALT-Header value */
if (strcmp($_SERVER['HTTP_X_ALT_REFERER'], $appID)!==0){
 exit('The X-Alt-Referer information recieved is invalid');
}

/* verify associated Content-MD5 header value */
if (strcmp(base64_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_MD5']), md5(serialize($_POST)))!==0){
 exit('The Content-MD5 value is incorrect');
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any reasons NOT to use this type of verification of POST data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to protect against? The Content-MD5 header is a decent solution to protect against transmission errors that aren't caught by the TCP checksum, which happens more often than most people realize. Against an attacker actively modifying the data it's completely useless as the attacker can just recompute the header.

The only reason not to use this header is one of performance, there is overhead on both client side and server side (think mobile clients for example). You have to weight the cost with the (small) protection it offers you.

I found this [blog entry](http://inkdroid.org/journal/2008/06/23/content-md5-considered-helpful/) helpful on the matter.

Comment: I am not certain I agree with the performance argument as no blocking takes place and the libraries are already loaded once the server pushes the JS and HTML to the client.

Comment: And how does it magically make the computing of the checksum instant and free?

Comment: Your right. There is some overhead in calculating the checksum to be appended to the content-md5 header value.